# Angular-Fullstack Generator: How to create a persistent file upload using the boilerplate?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

Thank you for reading this post.

As a newcomer to the programming community, I have what I believe to be a fairly easy question.

**How do you implement a file upload (particularly images) using the MEAN stack (yeoman angular-fullstack generator in particular)?**  *An explanation using the yeoman angular-fullstack boilerplate would be appreciated.*

In particular, could you please make a step-by-step explanation. **This is not recorded anywhere on the internet, so your help will be recognized and appreciated!** :-)

While there are numerous explanations out there, those explanations always answer a particular user's question (as do many other questions/answers) and are not applicable to general use cases.  Those explanations typically require one to be able to parse through numerous lines of irrelevant code, in order to absorb the information that's relevant. As such, a "noob" is not able to utilize the part of the code that is applicable to him/her. That is why I'm asking for an explanation using the boilerplate of a generator, so that myself and others may use this information -- now and in the future.

Using search engines and research, I have come across the predominate answer that ng-file-upload and multer can accomplish this task.  However, there is no rudimentary explanation of how this used implemented within a MEAN stack together (particularly, angular-fullstack -- the predominate MEAN stack implementation at this time).

Today, any general non-static website requires a file-upload implementation, and it seems extremely odd that there is very little documentation on this issue. I've read numerous O'Reilly books on MongoDB, but this issue is not addressed.  Images and Videos are essential to commercial-grade websites, and these topics should be documented in a way that is digestible for newcomers to MEAN programming.

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate any and all helpful answers and comments.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Unfortunately it is a very long way to ask for a tutorial, and then complain about the fact that tutorials don't exist already.  This is completely off topic here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Uploads are handled on the server stack ... so looking in database related docs would be wrong place to look. As for using a MEAN package... most of your searches will be for the specific part of the stack...angular, node, etc. Shouldn't be hard at all to find tutorials and docs for upload packages

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Maybe "tutorial" wasn't the right word to use @Claies, what I am asking for is a simple answer that states how to connect an Angular directive to populate information into MongoDB utilizing the angular-fullstack.  I haven not found any explanation that clearly states what lines of code need to be edited in order to make it work on the internet, and I believe that file-upload is such an essential part of websites/apps these days that there should be no shortage of clear-cut explanations.

Comment: even if you don't use the word tutorial, your question is still a description of a broad process you would like to do, with no indication that you have even tried any code.  any decent answer to this question would involve writing a full library, and would turn into a tutorial anyway.

Comment: @Claies thanks again.  I prefaced the question with "Angular-Fullstack Generator" so that any potential readers/answerers would know the base code being used.  Then, I am asking for an answer to that question based upon the boilerplate code that is created initially once it is made.  The rhetoric was used as a call to address not only my question, but to appeal for an answer that would be useful to other/future new programmers wishing to address this question.  My reading of  [StackHelp](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) incorporates this question, but for the use of the word "tutorial".

Comment: you are still missing my point, but it's not really appropriate to argue.  I really do want to help you come up with an answerable question, so I'll try one last time to explain my point.  Stack Overflow is not a *code writing service*.  We are professionals that want to help other professionals solve issues with the code they have written, not provide a full implementation of a solution from scratch.

Comment: And regardless of what you call it  "how to" that only has a general concept as starting point is just far too broad for the site guidelines. Web development requires lots of research and learning both front and back end simultaneously is a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

you can use my code which is MEAN project for image upload

https://github.com/RohitShedage/image-upload